# Parsing XML response also containing JSON in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, api, testing, postman

I want to verify specific JSON content matches a variable defined in the request and is in the correct location but am not having success. How do you think I might address this?

Postman Response received below:

```xml
<TESTResponseMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ContextToken>
        <SourceId>TESTSOURCE</SourceId>
        <SourceCounter>TESTSourceCounter</SourceCounter>
        <Priority>1</Priority>
        <ContextId>cb9bec3e-80d6-40a5-b7db-ec43bb1416df</ContextId>
    </ContextToken>
    <MessageBody>
        <Message>Data received and Commissioning started</Message>
        <HttpStatusCode>200</HttpStatusCode>
        <TestRequest>{"ImportMpxn":"1414023910008","InstallCode":"91D4D6FAB81DF7DED66ACEC82729C537","ChfDeviceId":"88-73-84-51-00-00-89-DB","ExternalTrackingId":"TESTSourceCounter","DeviceId":"30-EB-5A-FF-FF-5C-8F-38"}</TestRequest>
        <TestResponse>{"Item1":{"Success":true,"OrchestrationId":"99d0fe71-1ff9-4207-9a32-d027a349f82c"},"Item2":200}</TestResponse>
    </MessageBody>
</TestResponseMessage>
```

I have written the following assertion test but receive an error:

**Test Written**

```
pm.test("MPXN sent = MPAN submitted", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.TESTResponseMessage.TestRequest.ImportMpxn).to.eql(pm.variables.get("ImportMpan"));
});
```

**Error Response Received**

> `JSONError: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1 <TESTResponseMessage xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/20 ^`

Comment: You'll have to parse the XML first, locate the JSON values nodes and then parse them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first utilize the `xml2Json` library (which is built-in to Postman) to convert your response from XML into JSON, and then extract the node from that. So to get `ImportMpxn` from your example, try this:

```
pm.test("MPXN sent = MPAN submitted", function () {
    var xmlAsJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
    var testRequest = xmlAsJson.TESTResponseMessage.MessageBody.TestRequest;
    pm.expect(testRequest.ImportMpxn).to.eql(pm.variables.get("ImportMpan"));
});
```

However, note that your opening and closing XML tags are using different casing (`TESTResponseMessage` v `TestResponseMessage`) which xml2Json doesn't like as it's not syntactically correct; if you can amend them in the source file so that the values match, the above snippet will work.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for the above solution. I am now running the below test but am receiving a further error:

**Test**

pm.test("MPXN sent = MPAN submitted", function () {
    var xmlAsJson = xml2Json(responseBody);
    var TestRequest = xmlAsJson.TestMessage.MessageBody.TestRequest;
    pm.expect(TestRequest.ImportMpxn).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get('ImportMpan'));
});

**Error Response**

AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal '1414023910008'

Comment: P.S.

I also amended the payload to ensure syntactic consistency.